# OSX 10.9 Mavericks VirtualBox unable to use Bridged Networking

Tags: macos, virtualbox

Since upgrading to OSX 10.9 Mavericks VirtualBox machines that have a Bridged Network have been unable to start.

Installing VirtualBox again solves the problem temporarily, but this does not survive a reboot (or in my case kicking the power supply cable out!).

Has anyone come up with a permanent solution for this, or at least one that does not involve a fresh install?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a temporary solution.  It appears that on reboot not all the kernel extensions are loaded correctly.  However a restart of the VirtualBox startup item seems to resolve this and I can then start the machines.

```
sudo  /Library/StartupItems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart
```

Is the line that works for me, sometimes I have to run it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken regarding the issue here, simply enabling IP forwarding on the OS X host will resolve the issue:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```